# Какой паттерн можно применить?

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Какой паттерн можно применить для улучшения подерживаемости данного кода?

```
public class AppleDeviceStore {
public AppleDevice createDevice(String type, String color) {

    AppleDevice device = null;
    if (type.equals("IPhone")) {
        if (type.equals("white")) {
            device = new WhiteIPhone();
        } else if (type.equals("black")) {
            device = new BlackIPhone();
        } else if (type.equals("gold")) {
            device = new GoldIPhone();
        }
    }
    if (type.equals("IPad")) {
        if (type.equals("white")) {
            device = new WhiteIPad();
        } else if (type.equals("black")) {
            device = new BlackIPad();
        } else if (type.equals("gold")) {
            device = new GoldIPad();
        }
    }
    if (type.equals("IPod")) {
        if (type.equals("white")) {
            device = new WhiteIPod();
        } else if (type.equals("black")) {
            device = new BlackIPod();
        } else if (type.equals("gold")) {
            device = new GoldIPod();
        }
    }
    device.verifyPrice();
    device.calculateDeliveryPrice();
    device.reserveItem();
    device.sendNotification();
    device.sendToCustomer();
}
}
```

Comment: как у вас одна и та же переменная может иметь 2 значения? type.equals("IPhone") и type.equals("white"). наверно хотели color?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если рассуждать логически, то белый айфон по своим характеристикам не отличается от черного, т.е. цвет должен быть переменной класса:

```
public abstract class AppleDevice {

    private Color color;

    public AppleDevice(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}

public enum Color {
    WHITE, BLACK, GOLD;
}

public class IPhone extends AppleDevice {

    public static final String PRODUCT_NAME = "IPHONE";

    public IPhone(Color color) {
        super(color);
    }
}
```

Паттерн называется [Factory](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)), чтобы улучшить читаемость можно использовать оператор `switch`. Желательно при этом, чтобы название продукта не было рандомным, а задавалось где-то в самом классе.

```
public class DeviceFactory {

    public static AppleDevice build(String type, Color color) {
        switch ( type.toUpperCase() ) {
            case IPhone.PRODUCT_NAME:
                return new IPhone(color);
            // ...
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

Сервисные методы нужно вынести в отдельный класс, в котором будет инкапсулирована соответствующая логика.

```
public interface Store<T> {

    public boolean verifyPrice(T device);

    public int calculateDeliveryPrice(T device, Address address);

    public void reserveItem(Integer deviceID);

    public void sendNotification(T device, String email);

    public void sendToCustomer(Integer deviceID, T device);
}

public class AppleStore implements Store<AppleDevice> {

    @Override
    public boolean verifyPrice(AppleDevice device) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int calculateDeliveryPrice(AppleDevice device, Address address) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void reserveItem(Integer deviceID) {}

    @Override
    public void sendNotification(AppleDevice device, String email) {}

    @Override
    public void sendToCustomer(Integer deviceID, AppleDevice device) {}

}
```